# 'gnome-shell' process causing 100% Overall CPU utilization? What is going wrong?

Tags: gnome, cpu-load

Since morning today, my laptop has been freezing up frequently. Only option available at that time is to kill x-server(as ctrl-alt-backspace is the only thing which works that time). I checked "Task manager" and it shows "gnome-shell" process consuming upto 70% of CPU. What is going wrong and what can be done to fix it?

**Update**
Issue happened again and i captured few snapshots, which shows the consistent CPU percentage consumed by 'gnome-shell' process. You can also check the "graph" on top-center, which is continuously touching the roof!

[image]

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**

I've moved to Cinnamon Desktop. This problem was hampering my work productivity alot so finally made the switch and i'm pretty comfortable with it now.

Comment: After keeping the system idle for few minutes, the overall CPU consumption has gone down to normal level i.e. 13-30%

Comment: How about posting (and looking in) the output of `ps -el`?

Comment: Thanks, the issue has occurred 3-4 times now. Currently it has stopped after keeping system idle for couple of minutes so the output of "ps -el" doesn't show anything alarming. May be next time when it happens(and it happens quite frequently), i'll capture that. But from what I've seen, only gnome-shell process takes up bulk of CPU whereas others were only taking single-digit CPU %.

Comment: Is there a command which could show CPU consumption history?

Comment: The command is `top`. See this: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-find-out-linux-cpu-utilization.html You should try to Google before asking.

Comment: 'Top' doesn't show any history which was what I asked. It only shows you the real-time data of processes and their statistics, which i am already seeing in "Task manager".

Comment: What kind of history are you talking about then? You mean what processes were running in the past and are not running now? Try: `cd /var/log` or `dmesg`.

Answer (score 3):

I suffered the same problem (just using Gentoo/Linux as OS). Actually the gnome-shell-theme I used ("Transparent Atolm") seemed to create the problem. After rolling back to the default theme everything worked fine again.

Answer (score 0):

Cheese running in the background was making gnome-shell go in the 200-350% range for me, in case that helps someone. Check for something using a camera.

Answer (score 0):

Check:

1. Your background,
2. Your theme,
3. If you're running Google Cloud SDK.

Change all 3 to see if it helps.

Comment: Google Cloud SDK?

Answer (score -1):

I am having this exact same issue on my Dell laptop.I am using ubuntu-gnome 16.04.After two days i found that issue was intel graphics. i solved this issue by disabled secondary display.

setting->displays->secondary display->turn off. only primary display is acive now.that's all..........